# swift xcode play sound files from player list

Tags: ios, xcode, file, audio, swift

I am looking for a swift coding playing sound out of the player list and not sounds added as resource to your project.
 I mainly found the usage of
NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sound_name", ofType: "wav"))
    println(alertSound)
but for this you need to have the sound file in your bundle. But I couldn't find any example 
selecting audio files bought thru itunes and play them.

Any idea how to do this? Can I access my music layer playlist files and using them in my app?

Thanks for any code lines.
rpw

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These music files are represented by MPMediaItem instances. To fetch them, you could use an *MPMediaQuery*, as follows:

```
let mediaItems = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery().items
```

At this point, you have all songs included in Music App Library, so you can play them with a *MPMusicPlayerController* after setting a playlist queue:

```
let mediaCollection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: mediaItems)

let player = MPMusicPlayerController.iPodMusicPlayer()
player.setQueueWithItemCollection(mediaCollection)

player.play()
```

You might need to filter songs by genre, artist, album and so on. In that case, you should apply a predicate to the query before fetching the media items:

```
var query = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
let predicateByGenre = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: "Rock", forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyGenre)
query.filterPredicates = NSSet(object: predicateByGenre)

let mediaCollection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: query.items)

let player = MPMusicPlayerController.iPodMusicPlayer()
player.setQueueWithItemCollection(mediaCollection)

player.play()
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Linox, Thanks for the example I have tried
import MediaPlayer

let music = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
in the playground but getting an exception EXC_BAD_ACCESS code =1
Do you know if playground supports this?

Comment: It won't work on playground as you must have an application context to access the music library. Try to implement this code in the viewDidLoad() method. Please don't forget to mark my answer as correct if that suits you good. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Linox, I have tried in viewDidLoad 
but my the first line ->let mediaItems = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery().items
is always empty (nil)

Comment: Simulator Unsupported frameworks include:

External Accessory
Media Player 
I was searching for the root cause  2 days, ok its a one time finding , disappoiting

Comment: NOTE: iPodMusicPlayer() is deprecated in iOS 8. Use systemMusicPlayer() instead. :)